# Oil in 2011 Toyota Corolla

Tags: toyota, oil-change, corolla

My 2011 Toyota has 15,000 miles on it. I just got its oil changed, and the new place that I took it to told me that I NEED synthetic oil 0W-20 (so they put in "Castrol Edge 0W-20"). But they also told me that I only need to get the oil changed every 10,000 miles. The built-in oil reminder in the car reminds you to get new oil every 5,000 miles though.

So who is right: my car, or the mechanic? Is it safe to replace the oil after 10,000 miles? Thanks in advance for your advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manufacturers specifications are the ultimate authority.  It does seem like you can go 10,000 miles between changes [with synthetic oil](http://www.toyota.com/owners/web/pages/resources/maintenance/synthetic-motor-oil).  As long as the Castrol oil you've got is up to the same standard as Toyoto Synthetic, you're probably good for 10,000 miles.  As to whether you *need* synthetic, if Toyota says you should or must use synthetic, you need it.  Otherwise, you don't, especially if you drove it off the lot with conventional oil from the factory.  Check your owner's manual (I just took a look at a PDF excerpt from [Toyota](http://www.toyota.com/owners/web/pages/resources/owners-manuals), I see no mention of synthetic oil being required).

That being said, if it was my car and I planned on keeping it for many years, I'd use synthetic oil and change it ever 10,000 miles or so.

Answer (score 0):

You may use 5W-20 Regular Oil every 5,000 miles. Or 0W-20 Synthetic every 10,000 miles. Syntheticc
 cost more but, more mileage between changes and better gas mileage, plus better cold starting, are all benefits of synthetic. :)

Answer (score 0):

Toyota dealers recommend semi synthetic 10/30.as this what you in their services.

Comment: Can you provide a source for the statement? My Toyotas (2011 Toyota Yaris, 2016 Toyota RAV4 hybrid) all are recommended to use 0W-20, but for my 2011 Toyota Yaris the dealers sometimes put 5W-30 with no damage. 10W-30 seems too thick at freezing temperatures to me. Heck, even the 1989 Opel Vectra I used to drive was recommended to use 5W-30 and not 10W-30.